# (extract from istream and insert into ostream) operation: is >><T> os;

Tags: c++, templates, stream, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload `operator>>` in order to extract type `T` from `istream x;` and insert into `ostream y;`, i.e. `x >><T> y;`.

With

```
template<class T> istream& operator>>(istream& is, ostream& os)
{
    T a;
    is >> a;
    os << a;
    return is;
}
```

the prefix notation `operator>><string>(x,y);` compiles, but postfix notation `x >><string> y;` fails to compile with

```
test.cpp:29:9: error: expected expression
    x >><string> y;
        ^
test.cpp:29:10: error: unexpected type name 'string': expected expression
    x >><string> y;
         ^
2 errors generated.
```

and i guess the `>><T>` notation is just not valid.

Just curious if there is a way to get the postfix version to compile? Or maybe some thoughts whether an extract/insert operator makes sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. Operator overloading proceeds according to strict grammatical rules, so for any binary operator `@`, the expression `a @ b` considers overloaded functions `(a).operator@(b)` and `operator@(a, b)`.

The right thing in your case is to make a wrapper object:

```
template <typename T> class pass
{
    std::ostream & os_;
public:
    pass(std::ostream & os) : os_(os) {}

    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, pass & p)
    {
        T x;
        if (is >> x) { p.os_ << x; }
        return is;
    }

    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, pass && p)
    {
        return is >> p;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::cin >> pass<int>(std::cout);
```

Note that we're taking the `pass<T>` object by rvalue reference to allow this construction.